# Wordpress -> If Is Role Subscriber Show Image?

Tags: php, bbpress

So here's the deal..I have Wordpress + bbPress integrated with a membership software (aMember).

On my bbPress forums, under people's username i want to show the Wordpress roles (Not bbpress roles) of every member and also an image depending of the role of every member.

For example,

If user role is subscriber -> Show role under username in bbpress -> Also show an image below.

The reason why i want to show Wordpress roles (instead of bbpress roles) is that my membership software (amember) allows me to set different wordpress roles depending on the User's subscription. I have 2 different membership plans on my site (one free and on paid) and i want to show different images in my bbpress forums based on their plan.

I went through the bbPress templates and i found this code (in loop-single-reply.php):

```
<?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'sep' => '<br />', 'show_role' => true ) ); ?> // this shows the bbpress role
<?php echo 'Points: '.cp_getPoints(bbp_get_reply_author_id()); ?> // this shows the member points below the username - I use a points plugin)
```

Now how can i replace this code with a code that shows the Wordpress roles (not bbpress) for every user and also show an image under it depending on what roles it is. For example:

If Is Role "Subscriber" -> Show Role + Image Under It

If Is Role "Contributor" -> Show Role + Image Under It

If Is Role "Administrator" -> Show Role + Image Under It

I'm not a programmer so i have no idea how to accomplish this. Please help. I found some related code that i think i could use to make this work:

```
<?php if ( current_user_can('contributor') ) : ?>
Content
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now my failed attempt looks like this:

```
<?php 
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$current_user = $bbp_get_reply_author_id; // i think this is wrong :P
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
?>
<?php if ($user_role == 'administrator') : ?>

Show Role  
Show Image

<?php elseif ($user_role == 'editor') : ?>

Show Role
Show Editor Image

<?php elseif ($user_role == 'author') : ?>

Show Role
Show Author Image

<?php elseif ($user_role == 'contributor') : ?>

Show Role
Show Contributor Image

<?php elseif ($user_role == 'subscriber') : ?>

Show Role
Show Subscriber Image

<?php else : ?> 

Show Role

<?php endif ?>
```

I have no idea what i'm doing...The code above is something i found on Google.

Can anyone help?

I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This `<?php if ( current_user_can('contributor') ) : ?>` only checks the users capabilities and is used like this `<?php if ( current_user_can('edit_post') ) : ?>`

You could write a function like this in `functions.php`:

```
function user_role_check( $role, $user_id = null ) {

  $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( empty( $user ) )
    return false;

  return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
}
```

In your theme you would use it like this:

```
<?php if ( user_role_check( 'administrator' )): ?>

   Do this 

 <?php else: ?>

   Do this

<?php endif; ?>
```

Learn more about Roles and Capabilities: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: thank you for your answer. the problem is i need to use bbp_get_reply_author_id() to show the role & image below the username of every forum user in my bbpress forums. so i don't think wp_get_current_user() would work in this case. any other ideas?